# Organizing express.Router with a class?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm experimenting with organizing my routes with Express router and classes in Typescript. This is what I've tried so far. The `index.ts` file is supposed to reference the Notes class in the `notes.ts` file which exposes an endpoint via a private method.

So, for example, I have a file `index.ts`

```
import * as express from "express";
import rootRoutes from "./root";
import { Notes } from "./notes";
import accountRoutes from "./account";

const router: express.Router = express.Router();
router.use("/", rootRoutes);
router.use("/account", accountRoutes);
router.use("/notes", Notes.routes);

export = router;
```

and another file `notes.ts`:

```
import express, { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
const router: express.Router = express.Router();

export class Notes {

    constructor() {
        this.routes();
    }

    private routes(): void {
        //Get notes
        router
            .route("/")
            .get((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
                res.send("notes");
            });
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a private method `router.use("/notes", Notes.routes);`

To use it like you did, first you have to instantiate the class or make the method static.

Mixing class instance state with router state can be tricky, try to keep it free of any instance state.

Also I would suggest you to simplify that implementation, to something like this:

```
export class Notes {
    static handler(req: Request, res: Response): void {
       res.send('Hello from A!')
    }
}


app.get('/', Notes.handler);
```